# In-App purchase non-renewing subscription for multiple app users

Tags: ios, subscription, in-app

What is the best practice to offer a paid monthly subscriptions to unlock extra features inside my social media app ? I have my custom app-users stored in my backend that are independent from Apple ID accounts.

I would like to link a specific IAP subscription to only one app-account, so when I log in as a different app-user with the same device (same Apple ID) I don't have access to those features I bought for the first account.